# Flatten hierarchical column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the hierarchy can be found in the `id` column. However, I would like to split the main category (denoted by a capital letter in `id`) from the sub category (denoted by numbers)

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c("A", "1", "1.4", "C", "6.", "2.4.5"), building = c("Centro", "Main cafeteria", "Hall of winston", "Twin building block", "Hassel", "Right wing Twin"))

     id            building
1     A              Centro
2     1      Main cafeteria
3   1.4     Hall of winston
4     C Twin building block
5    6.              Hassel
6 2.4.5     Right wing Twin
```

I would like to get something like the dataframe below

```
dat2 <- data.frame(building = c("Centro", "Centro", "Twin building block", "Twin building block"),
                   part_building = c("Main cafeteria", "Hall of winston", "Hassel", "Right wing Twin"))

             building   part_building
1              Centro  Main cafeteria
2              Centro Hall of winston
3 Twin building block          Hassel
4 Twin building block Right wing Twin
```

Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split` like:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat$building, cumsum(dat$id %in% LETTERS)),
 function(x) data.frame(building=x[1], part_building=x[-1])))
#               building   part_building
#1.1              Centro  Main cafeteria
#1.2              Centro Hall of winston
#2.1 Twin building block          Hassel
#2.2 Twin building block Right wing Twin
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `replace` `building` values that is not a capital letter to `NA` and create a new column. Fill the `NA` values with previous non-NA and remove rows which has capital letters in `building`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(temp = replace(building, !grepl('^[A-Z]$', id), NA)) %>%
  fill(temp) %>%
  filter(!grepl('^[A-Z]$', id)) %>%
  select( building = temp, part_building = building)

#             building   part_building
#1              Centro  Main cafeteria
#2              Centro Hall of winston
#3 Twin building block          Hassel
#4 Twin building block Right wing Twin
```